# opencv Laplacian function not work effectively like in document

Tags: opencv

here is my code

```
img_original=cv2.imread("sudoku-original.jpg",0)
cv2.imshow("original",img_original)
laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(img_original,cv2.CV_64F)
cv2.imshow("laplace",laplacian)
```

I want result like in the document but It don't.

here is the link of document:https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_gradients/py_gradients.html#gradients

[image]

Comment: I have an article about `sudoku` recognition. If you can read Chinese, then it may help. https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/30956782

Answer (score 3):

```
laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(img_original,cv2.CV_64F)
```

The above line implies that the format of the image is CV_64F which is an array of float values. So when you use cv2.imshow() function, it works in a way like: values greater than 1.0 will be white pixels and values lesser than 0.0 will be black.

So you will need to convert it to CV_8U. There are many ways to do it,
I generally use this:

```
laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(img,cv2.CV_64F)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(laplacian,0,255.0,cv2.THRESH_TOZERO)
laplacian8 = np.uint8(thresh)
cv2.imshow('sud',laplacian8)
```

This gave me the result:

[image: Result]

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14539652/8580478) link to learn more about the problem.