# Embedding Laplacian variance inside Tensorflow bounding box [webcam]

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow

I am trying to make bounding box which will also show focus quality prediction like in example shown here:

Image from [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/58341/)

I want to do it in real time, using webcam.

I am already using `visualization_utils` to draw a boxes on my output (camera, **opencv**). Later I use function `cv2.Laplacian(image, cv2.CV_64F).var()`, but it gives me overall value of whole picture.

My goal is to calculate **Laplacian variation** inside the bounding box.

Could you please give me an advice or provide an example how it can be done?

Comment: try.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48108717/opencv-laplacian-function-not-work-effectively-like-in-document

Comment: so basically "how to compute the laplacian only inside a rectangle"?

Comment: @Miki Yes, but using visualization_utils I am not sure if it is possible to do :(

Comment: Thats what i thought, i thought one would dupe the image where rect is and crop... and do laplacian .. but i dunno...

Comment: There is a function `tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box` but I am not sure how to use it correctly