# cvDiv throw an exception

Tags: c, opencv

I'm using [opencv](/questions/tagged/opencv) version `1.0.0` (unfortunately can not use newer one) for basic image operations like addition, division etc.

Data structures i'm using are defined like so:

```
CvMat m1 = cvCreateMat(w, h, CV_16U);
CvMat m2 = cvCreateMat(w, h, CV_16U);
CvMat m3 = cvCreateMat(w, h, CV_16U);
```

and contain 16bit unsigned grayscale raw images.

Operations like addition, substraction are working just fine. On the other hand, operation `cvDiv(m1, m2, m3);` produces `Division by zero` exception.

It seems like mats have to be converted to `CV_32F`, but i could not find a way how to properly convert them using [opencv](/questions/tagged/opencv).

If i convert them manually (by my own function) i'm getting `Violation reading location` exception.

**My questions are following:**

1. How to convert `CvMat` from `CV_16U` to `CV_32F`
2. How to correctly divide two images using `cvDiv` function

Comment: `cvConvertScale` for the conversion. (BTW, what exactly do you mean by "convert them by hand"?)

Comment: Iam sorry for this misleading phrase. I have meant that i tried to create my own `cvDiv` function. Thanks for the tip, i will try out tomorrow and let you know. The scale for conversion from `16U` to `32F` should be 2^16/(Max-Min) -- right ? According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539498/change-type-of-mat-object-from-cv-32f-to-cv-8u).

Comment: The scaling is necessary only if you're going to use functions that expect floating point images to have values in range [0,1]. To map the full range of 16U to [0,1], you'd use scaling factor (1.0/((2^16)-1))). However, if all you need to do is some arithmetics, just leave the scale at 1 (or use the [`cvConvert`](http://opencv.jp/opencv-1.0.0_org/docs/ref/opencvref_cxcore.htm#decl_cvConvertScale) macro).

Comment: @DanMašek `cvConvert` works great and so `cvDiv` now. Thanks. It is not easy to search for such an old functions if everybody is using new `C++` versions these days. Could you, please, post it as answer, so iam able to mark this question as answered ? It may help somebody in the future.